# Orbeon : oracle and flat view

Tags: orbeon

I'm using oracle with orbeon and I would like to use the flat view feature. 
In properties-local.xml I have the following :

```
<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">


        <property as="xs:anyURI"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.app.uri.*.*.*"
                          value="/fr/service/oracle"/>

        <property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.service.oracle.datasource"     
        value="oracle"/>

        <property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.oracle.create-flat-view"            
        value="true"/> 

</properties>
```

Everything works fine for the persistence layer but the views are not created. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was implemented post-3.9 release. It will be included out-of-the-box in the next release of Orbeon Forms PE, but as of this writing, 3.9 being the latest release, you either need to use a [nightly build](http://www.orbeon.com/forms/download) or a custom build that specifically includes this new feature.